# Изменение системного времени на python

Tags: python, время

Я имею числовую переменную, мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы системное время (секунды) были равны этой переменной. Можно ли это как то реализовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А чему у вас равна переменная sec?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081310/python-module-to-change-system-date-and-time

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.